# Context menu (right click) not working for start menu items

Tags: windows-7, context-menu, start-menu, right-click

I have Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit and have regular updates, but my context menu (right click doesn't work) for the items in start menu cannot be displayed!! Is there any solution for this?
Also, i have switched off many services, which are the services essential for the above to happen!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was very simple, right click on Start button > Properties > Allow right clicks was there somewhere in Customize.

Answer (score 10):

manishKungwani's answer was right on - but to be more specific:

- Right-click on the Start menu button.
- Click on "Properties".
- The "Taskbar and Start Menu Properties" dialog box will come up, initially focused on the "Start Menu" tab.
- Click on the "Customize…" button (at the top of the pane).
- The "Customize Start Menu" selection menu will come up.
- The 8th (approximately?) major item down (in alphabetic order) is "Enable context menus and dragging and dropping". (It is confusing to have two dissimilar items together like that.)